# Using a drop down list to change language in mvc4 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, drop-down-menu, resx

I have an MVC4 web app (razor) that is supposed to be bilingual. I have a **Resources** folder in which I have 2 resx files, named **Home.resx** and **Home.de.resx**. I managed to make two links which change the language to **en** and **de**.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "en" })">English</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "de" })">Deutsch</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is what I put in the **HomeController.cs**:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang)
{
    var langCookie = new HttpCookie("lang", lang) { HttpOnly = true };
    Response.AppendCookie(langCookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { culture = lang });
}
```

Here is the code in **Global.asax.cs**:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var handler = Context.Handler as MvcHandler;
    var routeData = handler != null ? handler.RequestContext.RouteData : null;
    var routeCulture = routeData != null ? routeData.Values["culture"].ToString() : null;
    var languageCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["lang"];
    var userLanguages = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;

    // Set the Culture based on a route, a cookie or the browser settings,
    // or default value if something went wrong
    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(routeCulture ?? (languageCookie != null ? languageCookie.Value
           : userLanguages != null ? userLanguages[0] : "en"));

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureInfo.Name);
}
```

Also modified the **RouteConfig**:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
}
```

---

**Now**, the question is - how can I make this happen with a DropDownList?
I have tried with the following code which doesn't change the language:

```
<li id="language">
    <form class="form " id="Form1" method="post" name="forma">
    <input name="formDate" value="123" type="hidden">
        <div class="control-group input-select-wrapper">
            <select class="aui-field-select" id="Select1" name="forma_languageId" onchange="submitForm(document.forma);" title="Language (Changing the value of this field will reload the page.)">
                <option class="taglib-language-option" value="en" lang="en">
                    English
                </option>
                <option class="taglib-language-option" value="de" lang="de">
                    Deutsch
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</li>
```

Am I missing something? Or this isn't the right way?
Thanks